# How could I add a new host to the existing Ingress in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

As I can see the below page, I can set up two or three hosts in one Ingress.
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#name-based-virtual-hosting

But how do I add a new host to existing ingress?
I tried the commands like apply or patch, but it didn't work.

Is there anyone who know this solution?

```
kubectl patch -f sample-ingress.yml -p ' 
  {"metadata": {"name": "sample-ingress"}, "spec": [{
    "host": "39500000.sample.com",
    "http": {"paths": [{
      "backend": {"serviceName": "39500000", "servicePort": 8080}
    }]
  }}]
}'
The Ingress "sample-ingress" is invalid: spec.backend.serviceName: Required value
```

Comment: The above json was insufficient. spec.rules was required. But the existing was overwritten by the patch, so it was clear by new setting at all. I do not want to replace but add.

Answer (score 6):

I personally prefer to use **PATCH** as my preferred approach to add an new host to an existing kubernetes ingress.

The command is going to look like this:
`kubectl patch ingress my-ingress --type json --patch "$(cat patch.json)"`

where patch.json is

```
[
    {
        "op" : "add" ,
        "path" : "/spec/rules/-" ,
        "value" : {
            "host": "evil.facebook.com",
            "http": {
                "paths": [
                    {
                        "backend": {
                            "serviceName": "tracker-app",
                            "servicePort": 80
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
```

A few notes:
 - my-ingress is the name of the deployed ingress in the cluster
 - one can just paste the json instead of using this trick "$(cat patch.json)"

Also, the main thing about this solution is that it **leverages kubernetes own capabilities** to merge json according to [these rules](http://erosb.github.io/post/json-patch-vs-merge-patch/).

More information patching from an official source can be [found here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/).

Comment: Useful. I just had to get the actual name of my ingress file, using `kubectl describe ingress` as it wasn't `my-ingress`

Answer (score 4):

Here is my un-edited bash solution for this.

If there is any interest, I can re-write this to make it more transferable. I will leave comments in the script to guide you.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Update ingress with potential new hosts
# REQUIREMENTS: [An existing ingress with at least one host, and jq installed on host]
kubectl get ingress laravel-ingress -n=gitlab-ci -o json > original_json #CHANGE THIS VALUE TO QUERY YOUR EXISTING INGRESS
existing_hosts=()
exisiting_host_names=()

 # I pass 3 arguments into the script. The first 2 are potential new hosts (if they aren't in the ingress already, and the 3rd arg helps me build the service name)
 API_HOST=$1
 DASHBOARD_HOST=$2
 NAME=$3

name="$NAME"
potential_new_hosts=(
     "$API_HOST"
     "$DASHBOARD_HOST"
)
new_hosts=()

while read -r value
do
  existing_host_names+=("$value")
done < <(cat original_json | jq ['.spec.rules[] | .host'])

# Loop through potential new hosts and add any non-existing ones to a new array.
for potential_new_host in "${potential_new_hosts[@]}"; do
    i=0
    for existing_host in "${existing_host_names[@]}"; do
       if [[ "$existing_host" == "\"$potential_new_host\"," ]] ; then
           i=1
       fi
    done
    if [[ "$i" == 0 ]] ; then
        # A non-existing host, add to an array
        new_hosts+=("$potential_new_host")
    fi
done

while read -r value2
do
  existing_hosts+=("$value2")
done < <(cat original_json | jq ['.spec.rules[] | .'])

# Enable for debugging
#echo "Original json"
#cat original_json
#echo "Existing host names"
#printf '%s\n' "${existing_host_names[@]}"
#echo "New hosts"
#printf '%s\n' "${new_hosts[@]}"
#echo "Existing hosts before adding"
#printf '%s\n' "${existing_hosts[@]}"
#echo "Hosts after adding new ones"
########    

# Begin building of hosts json to patch ingress with
output_json=""
for existing_host in "${existing_hosts[@]}"; do
    output_json=("$output_json$existing_host")
done

# Truncate the last char in our json string (it's a ']', and we want to potentially add to this array for patching
output_json=${output_json::-1}

i=0
for new_host in "${new_hosts[@]}"; do
    # Add to our json object the new host names with my hard-coded config
    output_json=("$output_json,{\"host\":\"$new_host\",\"http\":{ \"paths\": [{ \"backend\":{ \"serviceName\":\"$name-laravel-web\",\"servicePort\":80} } ]} }")
i=1
done
printf '%s]\n' "$output_json" > new_json

if [[  "$i" == 1 ]] ; then
    echo "Ingress json has changed and should be updated."
    echo "OLD:"
    cat original_json
    echo "PATCH: \"spec\": {\"rules\": $output_json]}"
    kubectl patch ingress laravel-ingress -n=gitlab-ci -p="\"spec\": {\"rules\": $output_json]}"
else
    echo "Ingress json has not changed and will not be updated."
fi
```

Edit (fixed bugs and converted to single host per script execution)

```
#!/bin/bash
# Update ingress with potential new host
NEW_HOST=$1
INGRESS_NAME=$2
SERVICE_NAME=$3

echo "Running update-ingress for New host: $NEW_HOST, ingress: $INGRESS_NAME, service: $SERVICE_NAME"
echo " Downloading existing ingress config"
kubectl get ingress "$INGRESS_NAME" -n=gitlab-ci -o json > original_json
existing_hosts=()
exisiting_host_names=()

echo " $ kubectl get ingress $INGRESS_NAME -n=gitlab-ci -o json > original json && cat original_json"
cat original_json

name="$SERVICE_NAME"
potential_new_host="$NEW_HOST"
new_hosts=()

echo "Looping through json values1"
cat original_json | jq ['.spec.rules[] | .host']
for value in $(cat original_json | jq ['.spec.rules[] | .host']); 
do 
  # Replace all commas with ""
  value=${value/,/""}
  existing_host_names+=("$value")
  echo "Looping v1: value:$value"
  #printf 'Array: %s' "${existing_host_names[*]}"
done
echo "Right after values1"
i=0
for existing_host in "${existing_host_names[@]}"; do
   echo "Looping through existing host: $existing_host == $potential_new_host"
   if [[ "$existing_host" == "\"$potential_new_host\"" ]] ; then
       i=1
   fi
done
if [[ "$i" == 0 ]] ; then
    new_hosts+=("$potential_new_host")
fi

echo "Looping through json values2"
for value2 in $(cat original_json | jq ['.spec.rules[] | .']);
do
  existing_hosts+=("$value2")
  #echo "existing host! $values2"
  #printf 'Array: %s' "{existing_hosts[*]}"
done

echo "Original json"
#cat original_json

echo "Existing host names"
printf '%s\n' "${existing_host_names[@]}"
echo "New hosts"
printf '%s\n' "${new_hosts[@]}"
echo "Existing hosts before adding"
printf '%s\n' "${existing_hosts[@]}"
echo "Hosts after adding new ones"

output_json=""
for existing_host in "${existing_hosts[@]}"; do
    output_json=("$output_json$existing_host")
done

output_json=${output_json::-1}

i=0
for new_host in "${new_hosts[@]}"; do
    output_json=("$output_json,{\"host\":\"$new_host\",\"http\":{ \"paths\": [{ \"backend\":{ \"serviceName\":\"$SERVICE_NAME-laravel-web\",\"servicePort\":80} }, { \"backend\":{ \"serviceName\":\"$SERVICE_NAME-laravel-web\",\"servicePort\":443} } ]} }")
i=1
done
printf '%s]\n' "$output_json" > new_json

if [[  "$i" == 1 ]] ; then
    echo "Ingress json has changed and should be updated."
    echo "OLD:"
    cat original_json
    echo "PATCH: \"spec\": {\"rules\": $output_json]}"
    kubectl patch ingress "$INGRESS_NAME" -n=gitlab-ci -p="\"spec\": {\"rules\": $output_json]}"
else
    echo "Ingress json has not changed and will not be updated."
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

You can edit a resource using `kubectl edit` so `kubectl edit ing sample-ingress` should let you change the current Ingress.

Or you could try `kubectl get ing sample-ingress -o json`, which would give you the current state of `sample-ingress` in a json format, pasting this into your text editor would give you a good base for creating a manifest which you could then `kubectl replace -f`.

Comment: `kubectl edit` require manually fixing, I want to fix it automatically. year, I also think `kubectl get` -> `kubectl replace` would be better, but it causes "race condition". I afraid that parallel replacing miss sometimes.